# Konva shape on click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, konvajs

I'm trying to define a custom shape in Konva, I tried the following code which draws a rectangle, I want to log clicks on it but click detection doesn't work. Why?

I don't know where I'm wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Konva Custom Shape Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    var rect = new Konva.Shape({
      sceneFunc: function(ctx) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
    }});

    rect.on("click", function() {
        console.log("click");
    });
    layer.add(rect);
    stage.add(layer);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I read that there is a 1.6.7 version - I believe there have been a number of improvements in event detection of rotated custom shapes in this, and  maybe this extends to non-rotated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I have to say I have no idea about this library, but I was interested because the code looked fine.*

After trying your code with a regular shape and seeing that the event handler worked, it was definitely as issue with how Konva's event system detected clicks on a custom shape.

Checking [the official tutorial on custom shapes](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Custom.html)  and adding an event listener (which worked) made me make a side by side comparison, revealing that the only difference was that your code lacked this method call:

```
// Konva specific method
context.fillStrokeShape(this);
```

After adding that method call, your event handler works correctly.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/1.6.5/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Konva Custom Shape Demo</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
  <script>
    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    var rect = new Konva.Shape({
      sceneFunc: function(ctx) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.fillStyle = "white";
            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.rect(10, 10, 100, 100);
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fillStrokeShape(this);
    }});

    rect.on("click", function() {
        console.log("click");
    });
    layer.add(rect);
    stage.add(layer);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you. However I don't understand why I have to make that call. The tutorial says that call is needed only to do stroke and fill, which I was doing myself.

Comment: Read up on how Konva does hit testing. Briefly to detect clicks Konva checks the color of the pixel under the mouse pointer. If it has color then there is a hit. To do that it runs a parallel canvas on which it draws your shape then wants to fill it and stroke it with a single known color to provide a 'hit surface' for the color check. The call the fillStrokeShape() does that. Without it Konva does not know the shape of your control and therefore cannot make the click detection mechanism work.